# Inserting an Admob MEDIUM_RECT into Android design library's NavigationView's menu

Tags: android, admob, navigationview, android-navigationview, android-support-design

By using

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_ad"
        android:title="@null"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/sidebar_ad" />
```

I can use my custom layout and create a native ad inside the NavigationView. However, the list item's height seems to be fixed at the same value, which means it's impossible to change a specific item's height individually.

`View view = mNavView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_ad).getActionView()` does return the custom view I created, however `view.getParent()` returns null, which means there is no way to get the container's reference to `setMinimumHeight()` on it.

I have even thought of using reflection to hack `NavigationMenuAdapter`, but since it's a private inner class, I even don't know where to start.

Is using another drawer library / write my own drawer view the only way to go?

Comment: did you try `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: I just tried, it does no effect at NavigationView's menu.

Comment: can you share you `layout/sidebar_ad`